# How can I write exif data from a json-file into a jpg-image?

Tags: json, exiftool

I've created backups of exif information with

```
exiftool -j -w json picture.jpg
```

How can I now restore the exif information to the image file from the json-file?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at the man page? `-tagsFromFile` may do what you want...

Comment: -tagsFromFile seems only to "copy" tags from one jpg to another.

Comment: Thanks. -tagsFromFile worked better for me. The -json option just won't import, at least on an mp4 file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok found it. Might be interesting for others so I post it:

```
exiftool -json=picture.json picture.jpg
```

This writes the exif data from picture.json to picture.jpg

Comment: Thanx @Stefan - just what I was looking for. It doesnt make it very clear in `man`